# {if...else..} statement after group_by in dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

To illustrate what I'm trying to do, I'm using diamond dataset as an example. After group_by(cut), I want to do lm on each group, depending on the mean depth of each group,  and then save the model in the dataframe.

```
diamonds %>% group_by(cut) %>% 
            mutate(mean.depth=mean(depth)) %>% 
            {if (.$mean.depth>60) do(model=lm(price~x, data=.))
                else do(model=lm(price~y, data=.))}
```

This is what I got:

```
Error in function_list[[k]](value) : object 'mean.depth' not found
```

Spent an hour to fix it but failed.  Appreciate it if anyone can help.

Comment: I'd put the `if` inside the `do()` (probably in an anonymous function)

Comment: How about `do(model = lm( if(mean(.$depth) >60){price~x}else{price~y}, data = .)`. It's just `if`-ing the formulas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
diamonds %>%
    group_by(cut) %>%
    do(model=if(mean(.$depth) > 60)
                lm(price ~ x, data=.)
             else lm(price ~ y, data=.))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
diamonds %>% group_by(cut) %>% 
  mutate(mean.depth=mean(depth),
         form = ifelse(mean.depth>60, 
                       "price~x", 
                       "price~y")) %>% 
  do(model = lm(as.formula(.$form), data = .))
```

> ```
> Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
> Groups: <by row>
>
> # A tibble: 5 x 2
>
>         cut    model
> *     <ord>   <list>
> 1      Fair <S3: lm>
> 2      Good <S3: lm>
> 3 Very Good <S3: lm>
> 4   Premium <S3: lm>
> 5     Ideal <S3: lm>
> ```